# kendo grid virtual scrolling last row is missing

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a kendo web aaplication. I have a kendo grid and virtual scrolling is enabled.Last row is missing while scrolling the grid but i can see that record by filtering.In IE it is working perfectly.

total recors : 374

If I show 11 records in a page it is working perfectly in IE and chrome because 374/11 is 34(not a decimal).If a change total row number to 12 last row is missing in chrome but still IE is perfect.I was face an issue line initially scroll bar is not visible but I fix that issue by using below code.

```
function setVisibleScrollHeight() {
        var vs = grid.element.find('.k-grid-content').data('kendoVirtualScrollable');
        grid._rowHeight = gridRowHeight;
        vs.refresh();
    }
```

It's call after grid initialization.Inital scroll is ok now.Any help for last row missing?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual scrolling relies on calculations about the average row height, which is used to calculate the height of the fake vertical scrollbar.

**jQuery solution**

```
dataBound: function () {
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    var ht=0;jQuery('#grid').find("tr[role='row']").each(function(){ 
    ht+=parseInt($(this).height()); 
}); 
// ht - total rows height
jQuery("#grid").find(".k-scrollbar-vertical").find("div").height(ht);     /// set kendo scrollbar height to ht 
} ,1000);  
} //databound ends
```

**css solution:**

```
  #Grid  .k-grid-content  td
{
  height: 100px;
}
```

More details about css:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/last-row-gets-cut-off-when-using-virtual-scrolling-and-setting-the-grid-height-after-filtering#kBSbnkqkSU6AG9kBmm1KYA

Comment: While recommended from Telerik, the css solution is problematic if you end up with a cell whose height exceeds that entered. Another option is to set `white-space: nowrap;`. Your jQuery solution is pretty nice though. I wonder if there's another event other than dataBound that can be tied into in order to eliminate the set timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. It got resolved after specifying height of grid.

```
height:400
```